# One class can see the other's variables, the other can't?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my classes. I am trying to clean up my code by moving some stuff into another class.

Currently I have only used static methods, so I had to, for example.

If I wanted to use my `MemoryStream` and work with it, I had to put it into the method:

```
Static Void WorkMS(MemoryStream ms){}
```

So, I never had to call the reference from the other class, The class calls the method instead.

But if I want to work with stuff that can't be put like that, for example:

```
 void ListenRender(Thread ListenThread, Thread RenderThread, CancellationTokenSource CTSReceive)
{
    CTSReceive = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ListenThread = new Thread(() => CaptureClass.Listen(CTSReceive.Token));
    ListenThread.Start();
    RenderThread = new Thread(() => CaptureClass.Render(CTSReceive.Token));
    RenderThread.Start();
}
```

It doesn't work.

This method is in a class called, `FastMethods`.

`CaptureClass` is another (my main) class.

Both are public, and the methods `Listen/Render` are also public.

And if I look at what `CaptureClass` got with `CaptureClass.`, it doesn't show any variable, methods or anything, it just shows stuff for the form it seems, like `ActiveForm`, `DefaultFont`...

The `CaptureClass` is a partial class with Form if that matters.

I have tried searching on it, but I can't find anything that says you can't call methods from a partial class, so I don't see what the problem is.

EDIT 1:

An easy example:

`FastMethods` class got a method.

```
Static Void Method()
```

`CaptureClass` can then use `FastMethods.Method` to call it.

Now, `CaptureClass` got a method.

```
Static Void CapMethod()
```

`FastMethods` can't call it with `CaptureClass.CapMethod`, as it doesn't even exist there.

EDIT 3:

Is this correct.

In `CaptureClass`:

```
internal void Render(CancellationToken CTS)
{}

internal void Listen(CancellationToken CTS)
{}
```

In `FastMethods`:

```
 void ListenRender(Thread ListenThread, Thread RenderThread, CancellationTokenSource CTSReceive)
{
  CaptureClass Cap = new CaptureClass();

    CTSReceive = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ListenThread = new Thread(() => Cap.Listen(CTSReceive.Token));
    ListenThread.Start();
    RenderThread = new Thread(() => Cap.Render(CTSReceive.Token));
    RenderThread.Start();
}
```

And when I call it:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   FastMethods.ListenRender(ListenThread, RenderThread, CTSReceive);
}
```

Or is there something I should improve with it?

Comment: problem is not clear at all, please rephrase.

Comment: The problem is just, I can´t see anything from CaptureClass from other classes, Only stuff like ActiveForm, DefaultFont etc (Form stuff i guess), I can´t see any Variables, Methods, Threads, or Anything else, even if i put them as, Internal, Public or whatever.

Comment: what do you mean "It doesn´t work."? the threads must have started, so what went wrong?

Comment: Are the methods in the other class marked as static? If not, you need to create an instance of them. If they are, do the classes inherit correctly?

Comment: It doesn´t start or anything, I can´t see, i simply wrote the whole line RenderThread = new Thread(() => CaptureClass.Render(CTSReceive.Token)); , to try to "Force" it. But it can´t see CaptureClass.Render. At all, it´s like it doesn´t even exist.

Comment: @JensenSomers , No, but doesn´t matter, i can´t see anything, tried Static or whatever, nothing can be seen.  Not sure waht you mean with inherit correctly?

Comment: I think it's a reference problem, does all the classes are in a single project and a single namespace? or do you have more then one project/namespace

Comment: Can you provide a more extended code sample of how it looks?

Comment: They are in the same namespace and same project.

Comment: Don´t exactly know how to show it, but will try to.

Comment: Please copy the entire classes code

Comment: If i do that it will take to much space.

But i may have found something. I can use variables in methods if i set it to Public Static. So will check if i can get Methods working as well, hopefully i have just made some misstake.

Comment: if you didn't set the methods access level then it's gonna be private by default...

Comment: How can i use a non-static method and make it public? As someone mentioned i need to create an instance of them.

Comment: I set them to Public if i want them as public.

Comment: Somebody please point this guy to a C# introduction course on object orientation and access modifiers. /sigh

Comment: There are many tutorials explaing this. for example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/class

Comment: Got it to work thanks to No Idea For Name, so thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class, every method and every variable and property has an access level that can be:

- private - only the class itself can reference it
- protected - only the class itself and classes the inherit it can access it
- internal - only classes in the same namespace can access it
- public - everyone can access it.

for classes only internal and public access level are allowed.

for the rest, if you do not specifically state the access level, for example:

```
public int x;

protected void method()
{
}
```

then they are private, meaning no one would be able to see and use them but the class itself

for more information read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

to use a non static method in a class you need to create an instance. for example in class `FastMethods`, will be like this:

```
public class FastMethods
{
   public void MeMethod()
   {
      // Your code
   }
}
```

then you can access it like so:

```
FastMethods fm = new FastMethods();// Initiate the class
fm.MeMethod();// Call the method
```

Comment: I know that, but how can i access a method, like  " Internal/Public void Method(){} " from another class?

Comment: @user2587718 read my edit, let me know if something is still missing

Comment: ah Great! that´s what i wanted:)  - What happens when i Initiate the class though, does it use resources or somthing i need to keep check on?

Comment: @user2587718 those are a lot of very broad question, you should read on OOP in general and about the Garbage Collector. search it on google

Comment: Okay, guess it does use some resources as Static methods are preferred, but i got what i wanted, thanks:)

Comment: @user2587718 any time